# How to create a union type with components?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics

Let's say that I have a helper function that returns wrapper around a generic component with some constant

```
function fooBar(ComponentVariant: ComponentVariantType) {
  return (
    <Foo>
     <ComponentVariant>
       <Bar />
     </ComponentVariant>
    </Foo>
  );
}
```

where `ComponentVariantType` is something like `type ComponentVariantType = FunctionalComponentA | FunctionalComponentB | FunctionalComponentC`.

Right now I get a build error saying:

```
FunctionalComponentA refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.
FunctionalComponentB refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.
FunctionalComponentC refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.
```

Comment: How did you define `FunctionalComponentA `

Answer (score 0):

`FunctionalComponentA` is the value representing the function at runtime. To get the type of such a value you need to use the `typeof` type operator:

```
type ComponentVariantType = typeof FunctionalComponentA | typeof FunctionalComponentB | typeof FunctionalComponentC.
```

Although depending on how those components are defined, when `ComponentVariant` the props passed in will need to be compatible with **all** components.

```
declare const FunctionalComponentA: React.FC<{ a: string }>
declare const FunctionalComponentB: React.FC<{ b: string }>
declare const FunctionalComponentC: React.FC<{ c: string }>

type ComponentVariantType = typeof FunctionalComponentA | typeof FunctionalComponentB | typeof FunctionalComponentC

function fooBar(ComponentVariant: ComponentVariantType) {
  return (
    <div>
    <ComponentVariant a="" b="" c=""></ComponentVariant> /* Must have all props*/
    </div>
  );
}
```